# How to change url with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, url

Suppose it's in a.html.

How to change url to b.html with jQuery?

Comment: I think he means if you're on page a.html, how do you use jQuery to change the URL to b.html - It's a bad example because you would never do that, but you might want to add a hash tag to the end or something. i.e. `page.html` might need changing to `page.html#section` when a jQuery function is triggered. I personally don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you want to change the target (`href`) of a `<a>` element using jQuery?

```
$("a#your_id").attr("href", "b.html"); // where `a#your_id` is your selector
```

Or, you want to change the current location in the browser (redirect someone to another page)?

```
window.location = "b.html"; // No jQuery required for this!
```

Comment: I believe the location property is on the window object.

Answer (score 2):

if your question is how to change existing href=a.html to href=b.html, then this should work ..

```
$('a[href=a.html]').attr('href', 'b.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign b.html for your  tag, need to use 'src' attribute.

```
$('a#your_id').attr('src', 'b.html');
```